# Wrong "this" being used in nested closures

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to keep this minimal, but let me know if I'm being too minimal.

Suppose you have a class hierarchy like this, designed for generating HTML (inspired by the Kotlin tutorial; semi-pseudocode follows):

```
class Tag {
  protected val children = arrayListOf<Tag>()
  operator fun String.unaryPlus() = children.add(Text(this))
}
class TagWithChildren : Tag() {
  fun head(init: Head.() -> Unit) = initializeTag(Head(), init)
  fun script(init: Script.() -> Unit) = initializeTag(Script(), init)
  fun <T : Tag> initializeTag(tag: T, init: T.() -> Unit): T {
    tag.init()
    children.add(tag)
    return tag
  }
}
class Head : TagWithChildren()
class Script : Tag()
class Text(val str: Text) : Tag()
```

Notice that `Head` has `head` and `script` methods while `Script` doesn't.

Now you can construct a template that looks like this:

```
head {
    script {
        +"alert('hi');"
    }
}
```

Which works great! However, if the block passed to `script` tries to call methods that aren't available on `Script`, **it can call the method on Head instead**. For example,

```
head {
    script {
        script {
            +"alert('hi');"
        }
    }
}
```

not only isn't a compile error, it's actually equivalent to

```
head {
    script {
    }
    script {
        +"alert('hi');"
    }
}
```

which is *super confusing*, from a template author's perspective.

Is there any way to prevent method lookups from traveling up the scope like that? I *only* want it to look at the innermost scope.

---

UPDATE 11/24/2016:
Kotlin 1.1-M03 has introduced scope control, which I believe solves exactly this problem. https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/11/kotlin-1-1-m03-is-here/

Comment: Sorry, what is it `Head < TagWithChildren` in your first code snippet? Could you please post the real declarations instead, because small details matter when talking about builders and scopes.

Comment: @voddan done...sorry about that, thought I was being generic when really I was just using Ruby subclassing syntax.

Comment: are you sure this what you have in you code? I am surprised it works at all, frankly. `fun head(init: Head.() -> Unit) = children.add(Head())` - you do not use `init` here

Comment: I'm leaving out a few of the less relevant details. I'm just trying to see a way if I can opt out of the scope traversal that the Kotlin compiler does.

Comment: As I said, details matter here, but that's up to you. As for now, you do not call the `init` methods anywhere, and i can't imagine it working without it. Maybe you meant `fun head(init: Head.() -> Unit) = children.add(Head().init())`

Comment: Please make sure you code does have the effects you are asking about

Comment: I added a couple more details.

Comment: what you mean a couple more? If you want help with your code, you would better post it as it is. I don't want to be rude, just station the fact

Comment: The question is already too complex, and I've provided more than enough details. The problem is, in this case, the `script` method always gets called on the `Html` instance (produced by the `html` closure), when I'd like it to *only* look for the `script` method on the `Script` instance (provided by the first `script` closure) and subsequently fail. That makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: I confirm the shadowing does not work properly for that case, leaving methods of an outer scope inside an inner scope

Comment: Sorry, @max, I got frustrated by code not working after copy-pasting it in IDE. I apologise.

Comment: That's alright; I should have started with actual code to begin with, since the details could be important (e.g. the exact method signature). Thanks for looking, @voddan.

Answer (score 3):

The current behavior is intentional. Code in a lambda has access to receivers of all enclosing scopes. It is possible that a future version of Kotlin will add a modifier that will restrict a lambda with receiver to calling methods on that receiver only and not the enclosing scopes, but in the current version there's no way to change that behavior.

Comment: so, is there a way to create type-safe builders? workaround?

Comment: Thanks @yole. This does make sense -- it's the way people expect closures to work, and in the non-builder case is generally what people want. Heck, even I want it for variable access but not method access, which is admittedly a bit arbitrary. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Incidentally this behavior is basically documented on this old article on [Kara](https://jaxenter.com/type-safe-web-with-kotlin-106187.html) I stumbled across, in the paragraph starting "Last question".

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, I can have it fail at runtime if I change the classes to look like this:

```
open class Tag {
  operator fun String.unaryPlus()
  // pulled up from TagWithChildren, call protected method
  fun head(init: Head.() -> Unit) = addChild(Head())
  fun script(init: Script.() -> Unit) = addChild(Head())

  // throws in Tag
  open protected fun addChild(t: Tag) = throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
class TagWithChildren : Tag() {
  // overridden to not throw in subclass
  protected override fun addChild(t: Tag) = children.add(t)
}
```

This way, *every* Tag has the builder methods (solving the scoping problem), but actually calling them may result in a runtime failure.

Comment: Another alternative workaround is to call the `head` and `script` builder methods on a *particular object*, i.e. either `this.script`/`this.head` (if receiver isn't passed as an argument, using `apply`) or `tag.script`/`tag.head` (if receiver is passed as argument, using `let`). Still, cumbersome.

Comment: you can `deprecate` the `Tag.addChild` method so that IDE will cross out it and remove from the complition